# Pay back loan with an annual withdraw

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I was given question 7b as homework:

[image]

I am guessing that there are numerous ways of approaching this.

The one method I have tried was to calculate the effective interest year for the year.

Then come up with something like this:

$180000 = (x-2500)\cdot(1.1157^4-\frac{1}{1.1157})\cdot1.1157$

$X$ would represent the annual-payement thus I divide it by $12$ to get the monthly payment.

Yet my answer does not match that of the book being $4046.34$.

Comment: Keep in mind that once the first monthly payment is made, the principal has decreased, and less interest will accumulate during the following month. Trying to do things on a yearly basis might miss that. But maybe you could explain how you got the number 1.1157.

Comment: @NateEldredge $1.1157 = (1 + \frac{0.11}{12})^{12}$ which I believe is the effective annual interest rate (plus 1) and equals $r^{12}$ in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r = 1 + \frac{0.11}{12} = 1.009166666$ be the monthly interest rate plus $1$ and, to simplify the equations below, let

$$R = \dfrac{r^{12} - 1}{r - 1}$$

Let $P_i$ be the principal after $i$ years, and let $X$ be the monthly repayment.

$$P_0 = 182500$$

$$P_1 = P_0 r^{12} - RX + 2500$$

$$P_2 = P_1 r^{12} - RX + 2500$$

$$P_3 = P_2 r^{12} - RX + 2500$$

$$P_4 = P_3 r^{12} - RX$$

$$0 = P_5 = P_4 r^{12} - RX$$

Therefore, repeatedly substituting these $P_i$ values:

\begin{eqnarray*}
0 &=& (P_3 r^{12} - RX) r^{12} - RX \\
&& \\
&=& P_3 r^{24} - RX r^{12} - RX \\
&& \\
&=& (P_2 r^{12} - RX + 2500) r^{24} - RX r^{12} - RX \\
&& \\
&=& P_2 r^{36} - RXr^{24} + 2500 r^{24} - RX r^{12} - RX \\
&& \\
&=& (P_1 r^{12} - RX + 2500) r^{36} - RXr^{24} + 2500 r^{24} - RX r^{12} - RX \\
&& \\
&=& P_1 r^{48} - RXr^{36} + 2500 r^{36} - RXr^{24} + 2500 r^{24} - RX r^{12} - RX \\
&& \\
&=& (P_0 r^{12} - RX + 2500) r^{48} - RXr^{36} + 2500 r^{36} - RXr^{24} + 2500 r^{24} - RX r^{12} - RX \\
&& \\
&=& P_0 r^{60} - RXr^{48} + 2500 r^{48} - RXr^{36} + 2500 r^{36} - RXr^{24} + 2500 r^{24} - RX r^{12} - RX \\
&&
\end{eqnarray*}

Re-arranging this to solve for $X$ we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
RX(r^{48} + r^{36} + r^{24} + r^{12}) &=& P_0 r^{60} + 2500 r^{48} + 2500 r^{36} + 2500 r^{24} \\
&& \\
X\dfrac{r^{60} - 1}{r-1} &=& P_0 r^{60} + 2500 r^{48} + 2500 r^{36} + 2500 r^{24} \\
&& \\
X &=& \dfrac{(P_0 r^{60} + 2500 r^{48} + 2500 r^{36} + 2500 r^{24})(r-1)}{r^{60} - 1} \\
&& \\
&=& \$4045.08
\end{eqnarray*}

There could be some rounding error explaining the discrepancy between this and the book's answer. There might be a simpler method than this or some shortcuts I'm not aware of - my background is in math rather than finance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a very long solution though :/ Not that it is  bad, but I am sure there must be something shorter

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to treat the additional withdrawals as a separate cash flow, and to compute its present value:  if $2500$ is borrowed immediately and at the beginning of each year for four years, then its present value is $$2500 \ddot a_{\overline{4}|i} = 2500 (1+i) \frac{1 - (1+i)^{-4}}{i},$$ where $i$ is the effective annual interest rate.  Then the present value of the total loan is $180000 + 2500 \ddot a_{\overline{4}|i}$.  The present value of the total series of payments is $K a_{\overline{60}|j}$, where $K$ is the monthly level payment at the end of each month, and $j$ is the monthly interest rate.

Comment: I have been trying to implement a solution with this idea to treat the withdrawls as separate cash flow. I tried your proposal, yet I must be going wrong somewhere, since I am not yielding the right answer

Comment: And I don't think 2500 is borrowed from the loan immediately, since there is no money in the annuity yet

Comment: @LukeTaylor I don't agree with your comment for the following reason. After repayments for a year, the outstanding balance is now X (say). A withdrawal of 2500 from the bank increases the outstanding balance to X + 2500. Interest for the next period will be calculated on this amount instead.